# Rails 3 If Statement,,, IF XXX Equals At Least One (Var1, Var2, Var3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is the following statement possible with Rails/Ruby? If so, how :)

IF XXX Equals At Least One (Var1, Var2, Var3)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
if [v1, v2, v3].any?{|v| v=="XXX"}
 p "Success"
end
```

OR

```
if [v1, v2, v3].include?("XXX")
 p "Success"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if [a, b, c].find_index(XXX)
```

Sounds simple enough. And there's nothing wrong with classical way too:

```
if XXX == a || XXX == b || XXX == c
```